DBT/Snowflake - identify updated and inserted rows per model
my stakeholders are requesting that after each model that updates or inserts new data (through merge) into some table, a log table needs to be updated with something like this:
log_table:
TABLE_LOADED    INSERTED_ROWS     UPDATED_ROWS
TAB_1           1500              1000

Any idea on how to approach this? How to identifies maybe with a post hook or a package that counts the inserted rows and updated rows separately?
Thanks

Apart from the Usage view in Snowflake, my suggestion is to leverage the row level metadata in your every model(s) (ref to https://infinitelambda.com/dbt-observability-row-level-metadata/), something that if you got the timestamp fields in your model e.g. inserted_at, updated_at, you could probably achieve count the rows:

row inserted: inserted_at = updated_at = T1
row updated: inserted_at = T1, updated_at = T2
(optional) row deleted: inserted_at = T1, updated_at = T2 and is_deleted = true

By having these things, you could use pre/post-hook to count rows and insert it to log table:

INSERTED_ROWS:

select  count(*)
from    {{ this }}
where   inserted_at = updated_at
    and inserted_at > {{ run_start_at }} 
    --or better to have a variable in the model that hold the the start time of the model (be mindful of the timezone)


UPDATED_ROWS:

select  count(*)
from    {{ this }}
where   inserted_at < updated_at
    and inserted_at > {{ run_start_at }} 
    --or better to have a variable in the model that hold the the start time of the model (be mindful of the timezone)

Hope this helps!

If you are using dbt, as the post tag suggests, you could leverage SELECT's dbt_snowflake_monitoring package (https://github.com/get-select/dbt-snowflake-monitoring).
It does a bunch of transformations around Snowflake's account_usage schema tables, and it makes it super easy to track stuff like the one you're after.
For instance, if I want to get a log of the inserted/updated rows in my incremental model using the merge strategy on a given date, I just need to run the following query:
select
    dbt_metadata:node_id::varchar as model_id,
    rows_inserted,
    rows_updated,
    start_time,
    end_time
from <your_db>.<your_schema>.query_history_enriched
where start_time >= '2024-04-25'::date
    and dbt_metadata:node_id::varchar = 'model.<dbt_project>.<model_name>'
    and query_type = 'MERGE'
order by start_time asc;


Query_history will return the ROWS_INSERTED and ROWS_PRODUCED (inserts+updates). Hence for updates you could use ROWS_PRODUCED-ROWS_INSERTED to get the value.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history
You could also use the GET_QUERY_OPERATOR_STATS function:
Example:
select OPERATOR_STATISTICS
from table(get_query_operator_stats('<Query ID'))
where operator_type='Merge';
Please review the below documentation for more information:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_query_operator_stats#operator-statistics
